# puppet install multiple samba packages with different version

Tags: installation, puppet, package, samba

I have a mixed environment where I need to install samba/samba3x, libsmbclient packages onto different red hat servers. What is the best way to write the module, should I write a separate module for each package OR can I write one module that will use all packages AND how do I deal with different versions? What is the best way to do this?

Here is the layout:

```
Redhat 5:

Host-A:
samba3x-3.6.23-12.el5_11
libsmbclient-3.0.33-3.41.el5_11  

Host-B:
samba-3.0.33-3.41.el5_11
libsmbclient-3.0.33-3.41.el5_11  

-------------------------------

Redhat 6:

Host-C:
samba-3.6.23-35.el6_8.x86_64
libsmbclient-3.6.23-35.el6_8.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here, and which one you use depends on exactly what you want to do.

If you just want to install the latest version or *a* version of the packages, simply use `ensure => installed`. This will make sure you have the package installed, but won't update or install them. The packages are named the same on RedHat 5 and RedHat 6 so it's not too tricky:

```
package { ['samba', 'libsmbclient']:
  ensure => installed
}
```

If you need a *specific version* of the packages, you can use the `params.pp` pattern which became popular in with many modules. Inside the params.pp, have a case statement which determines your required package version and inherit it from there. It might look a little bit like this.

params.pp

```
class samba::params {
case $::operatingsystemmajrelease {
 '5': { 
    $samba_version = '3.6.23-12.el5_11'
    $libsmb_version = '3.0.33-3.41.el5_11' 
  }
 '6': {
    $samba_version = '3.6.23-35.el6_8.x86_64'
    $libsmb_version = '3.6.23-35.el6_8.x86_64'
  }
}
}
```

init.pp

```
class samba (
  $samba_version = $samba::params::samba_version,
  $libsmb_version = $samba::params::libsmb_version
) inherits samba::params {

  package { 'samba3x':
    ensure => $samba_version
  }
  package { 'libsmbclient':
    ensure => $libsmb_version
  }
}
```

Now I notice your RHEL5 servers have different samba versions on them. If you need to support *that* you'll need to use something like [hiera](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/) to override the parameters above on a per node basis. This is really discouraged in Puppet, so I would advice you to think carefully before going down this route, and ask if it wouldn't be easier to get everything on the same version.

Comment: Thank You Frap! Your reply is very helpful. So just to clarify is it best to use params.pp or to go with hiera for package version and etc. Unfortunately I can't standardize the package versions across the board. Some systems need to have different versions.

Comment: I would use params.pp and hiera in combination where possible. It's not an either/or situation, the flexibility means you can do whats best for you.